# how can I change the lock I have aquired in a synchronized block, change it, and notifyAll() without getting java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException?

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization, wait

I know that questions have been asked about changing the lock in a synchronized block, but in my client side of multiThreaded socket programming I have a status enumeration in my class and every time I want to change it I get the lock and make the changes. At the same time another thread is waiting (it also gets the same lock and after reaching the wait method lets go of it) to observe the changes after the changer thread makes its changes and calls notifyAll().
now if I want to notifyAll() on an object(i mean the state enum) which is changed I get java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException!
I considered aquiring another shared final object as my lock but in this way maybe the threads still be able to manipulate state enum. what is the best approach??
Any answer will be appreciated.
this is part of my code:

this is the changer thread:

```
synchronized (client.getStatus()) {
    client.setStatus(ClientState.successfulRegistration);
    client.getStatus().notifyAll()
}
```

and this is the waiting thread:

```
synchronized (client.getStatus()){
    try {
            client.getStatus().wait();
            System.out.println("signMeIn notified");
            ClientState result = client.getStatus();
            System.out.println(result);
            if(result.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("successfulSignIn") )
                //do sth
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Why are you locking the `ClientStatus.FOO` value? You should be locking the `client` object. If you do not want to lock the whole `client` object, just create an extra `private Object statusLock` in your client class and lock that in the getter/setter.

Comment: It looks like you are locking the previous status, you are then updating it to the new status object and notifying the new status.  You need to lock something that is not going to change inside the synchronized block.

Comment: And how can anybody be waiting on the new status value? and how will they know which client it is for? You need to synchronize on the client, and notify on it, and the other threads need to wait on it.

Comment: locking the whole client object, that was my first approach,
but for the sake of clean coding I changed it like this.
Because I am just changing the state not the whole client.

Comment: Yes, I am locking the previous state and updating it and notifying the updated state with no thread waiting for it and thus the previous waiting thread waits in a deadLock

Comment: maybe I want to change other properties of my client other than its state, what then I can't till I get its lock that way you mention.

Comment: My problem is I want my waiting thread to get the state after The changing thread has changed it, not before it and get inaccurate status

Comment: I am locking the previous state, updating it and notifying the updated state without having its lock.

Comment: I have really confused following two things, what object you synchronize on:
the one you don't want to be changed(like the state enum) or the one you don't want to be mutated(like the Client)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in this code:

```
synchronized (client.getStatus()) {
    client.setStatus(ClientState.successfulRegistration);
    client.getStatus().notifyAll()
}
```

You are only allowed to notifyAll() on an object you locked. But one line above you replaced the object with a different one. It is a really bad idea to change a lock object. Usually you will use "this" or you use a private object.

I would suggest the following solution:

```
public synchronized void setStatus(T status) {}
public synchronized T getStatus() {}
```

The wait() and notifyAll() methods are only needed if you are waiting on a condition and want to release the lock. Here an example:

```
public synchronized void add(T element) {
   while(full) {
     wait();
   }
   data.add(element);
   notifyAll();
}

public synchronized T remove() {
    while(empty) {
      wait();
    }
    T item = data.getAndremove();
    notifyAll();
    return item;
}
```

In this examples are many hidden concepts. First you need a while-loop for the waiting. Because if you wait and gets notified you are back in the ready-to-run-queue. But you do not know if the condition still holds so that you have to recheck the condition. This is why you use a while-loop instead of a if().

The second concept is known by notify-and-resume. It is possible to notify() and keep the lock. So you do not have to put the notify() at the end.

The third concept is the difference between notify() and notifyAll(). The first one only wakes one thread. If the data is empty and you wakes up a thread that wants to remove something so there would be a dead-lock. If you wake-up all, all will check if the condition is met and try to proceed.

Here an other example that matches more your code:

```
public synchronized void doSth() {
   while(client.getStatus.equals("WAIT") {
        wait();
   }
   System.out.println("Status isn't wait");
}
```